# $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}(\phi(0)-\phi(\epsilon))\ln\epsilon=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous differentiable function. Is it true that

> $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}(\phi(0)-\phi(\epsilon))\ln\epsilon=0?$$

I think this can be proved through an infinitesimal comparison, but I have no idea how to start with.

Any hint would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{\phi(\epsilon)-\phi(0)}\epsilon=\phi'(0)$$

so

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left(\phi(0)-\phi(\epsilon)\right)\log\epsilon=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\frac{\phi(0)-\phi(\epsilon)}\epsilon\epsilon\log\epsilon=-\phi'(0)\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\epsilon\,\log\epsilon=0$$

The one-before-the last step is due to the fact that both limits exist and are finite.

Answer (score 2):

Using Taylor expansion under the hypothesis $\phi(\epsilon)-\phi(0)=\phi'(0)\epsilon+o(\epsilon)$ so that:

$(\phi(\epsilon)-\phi(0))\ln(\epsilon)=\phi'(0) \epsilon \ln(\epsilon)+\ln(\epsilon)o(\epsilon)$

Now we observe:

$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \epsilon \ln(\epsilon) =0$

and that:

$\ln(\epsilon)o(\epsilon)=\ln(\epsilon)\epsilon \cdot o(\epsilon)/\epsilon \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Use " \ " before "lim", "log", etc. to make them appear neater.